# Unexpected result in multithreaded program

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

This simple program has a shared array and 2 threads:
first thread - shows sum of values in the array.
second thread - subtracts 200 from one cell of the array and adds 200 to another cell.

I would expect to see the results: 1500 (sum of the array), 1300 (if the display occurs between the subtraction and the addition).

But for some reason, sometimes 1100 and 1700 appear, which I can't explain...

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank();
        bank.CurrentSum.start();
        bank.TransferMoney.start();
    }
}

class Bank {
    private int[] Accounts = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    Thread CurrentSum = new Thread("Show sum") {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                System.out.println(Accounts[0] + Accounts[1] + Accounts[2]
                        + Accounts[3] + Accounts[4]);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread TransferMoney = new Thread("Tranfer"){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0; i<50000; i++)
            {
                Accounts[rnd.nextInt(5)]-=200;
                Accounts[rnd.nextInt(5)]+=200;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because the addition of the five values is not atomic, and may be interrupted by the decrement and increment happening in the other thread.

Here's a possible case.

- The display thread adds `Accounts[0]+Accounts[1]+Accounts[2]`.
- The updating thread decrements `Accounts[0]` and increments `Accounts[3]`.
- The updating thread decrements `Accounts[1]` and increments `Accounts[4]`.
- The display thread continues with its addition, adding `Accounts[3]` and `Accounts[4]` to the sum that it had already partially evaluated.

In this case, the sum will be 1900, because you've included two values after they've been incremented.

You should be able to work out cases like this, to give you sums of anything between `700` and `2300`.

Comment: Thanks! But now, based on this understanding, why can't I get a result as big as I want? Maybe before the addition of Accounts[0] there were many increments of it, then before the addition of Accounts[1] there were many increments of it, and so on. Why do you say that the extreme results are bounded?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I've thought about it again, and I don't think the results are bounded.  It's just that the more extreme results are less and less likely - I mean, you should be getting `1500` most often, then `1300` slightly less often, then `1700` quite a bit less often than that, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the values in an atomic or thread safe manner.  This means sometimes you see two more -200 than +200 and sometimes you see two more +200 than -200. As you iterate over the values it is possible to see a +200 value but the -200 value is an earlier value and you miss it, but you see another +200 update again missing the -200 change.

It should be possible to see up to 5 x +200 or 5 x -200 in rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps on purpose, you are not doing the addition operation atomically.

That means that this line:

```
System.out.println(Accounts[0] + Accounts[1] + Accounts[2]
                        + Accounts[3] + Accounts[4]);
```

Will run in multiple steps, any of which can occur during any iteration of the second thread.

```
1. Get value of Accounts[0] = a
2. Get value of Accounts[1] = b
...So on
```

The addition then happens after all the values are pulled from the array.

You can imagine that 200 is subtracted from Accounts[0], which is dereferenced by the JRE, then in another loop of the second thread, 200 is removed from Accounts[1], which is subsequently dereferenced by the JRE. This can result in the the output you see.

Answer (score 0):

The Accounts variable is being accessed from more than one thread, one of which modifies its value. In order for the other thread to reliably read the modified values at all it is necessary to use a "memory barrier". Java has a number of ways of providing a memory barrier: synchronized, volatile or one of the Atomic types are the most common.

The Bank class also has some logic which requires the modifications to be made in multiple steps before the Accounts variable is back in a consistent state. The synchronized keyword can also be used to prevent another block of code that is synchronised on the same object from running until the first synchronized block has completed.

This implementation of the Bank class locks all access to the Accounts variable using the mutex lock object of the Bank object that owns the Accounts variable. This ensures that each synchronised block is run in its entirety before the other thread can run its own synchronised block. It also ensures that changes to the Accounts variable are visible to the other thread:

```
class Bank {
    private int[] Accounts = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    Thread CurrentSum = new Thread("Show sum") {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                printAccountsTotal();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread TransferMoney = new Thread("Tranfer"){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0; i<50000; i++)
            {
                updateAccounts();
            }
        }
    };

    synchronized void printAccountsTotal() {
        System.out.println(Accounts[0] + Accounts[1] + Accounts[2]
                + Accounts[3] + Accounts[4]);
    }

    synchronized void updateAccounts() {
        Accounts[rnd.nextInt(5)]-=200;
        Accounts[rnd.nextInt(5)]+=200;
    }
}
```